# Sphinx, Kivy and autodoc: warning and issues to create documentation

Tags: python, kivy, warnings, python-sphinx

I would like to create documentation of my code in Sphinx. I installed everything and made some simple trial that worked fine. (I run sphinx-quickstart, edit the conf.py to include modules' path, work with a tutorial to know how sphinx works etc. etc.)

Yet, my code import many Kivy libraries. And when I want to create the documentation on module that import Kivy, it fails.

For instance, if I have my main.py like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App

def test_app(a,b):
    """ Test documentation """
    print a + b

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_app(1,2)
```

Then, if I run

> make clean && make html

I have the following wanring (and no doc edited..):

> *WARNING: /home/math/drphytoscan/source/autodoc.rst:4: (WARNING/2) autodoc: failed to import module u'src.main'; the following exception
> was raised: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line
> 657, in import_object
> **import**(self.modname) File "/home/math/drphytoscan/source/src/main.py", line 14, in  from
> kivy.app import App ImportError: No module named app*

Note: If I erase the line:

```
from kivy.app import App
```

it works. That shows that it comes from the Kivy lib import.

PS: I have Python 2.7.9, Kivy 1.9.1 and Sphinx 1.6.3 on a Debian Jessie

Answer (score 0):

From the note at the top of the [documentation for autodoc](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html):

> For Sphinx (actually, the Python interpreter that executes Sphinx) to find your module, it must be importable. That means that the module or the package must be in one of the directories on sys.path – adapt your sys.path in the configuration file accordingly.

Comment: I checked my sys.path and it seems ok. Sphinx is in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages and kivy : /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages. Both are there when I type "sys.path" on a python command line shell.

Comment: Perhaps the warning on the same documentation page may help? Ideally you would install everything into a virtual environment, and invoke Sphinx from within it.

Comment: @Steve Piercy - "Ideally you would install everything into a virtual environment..." and here I was trying to generate doc for my project with my sphinx install NOT in that project's venv, of course its not going to find my other installed packages.